# What's a quick, easy way to send HTML emails to myself to test them?

Tags: html, email, testing, send

I've been given the task of optimizing HTML emails for different email/webmail clients. I used to test the HTML file by doing a trick in Outlook Express, to make it send the raw HTML, but Microsoft seems to have stopped supplying Outlook Express now (I think "Live Mail" is supposed to replace it).

So my question is, is there a simple, quick way to send HTML emails? Maybe even a freeware program that does the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) can help with that -if you just need to receive and view any emails sent by your application.

Comment: https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/TestMailServerToolSetup.exe

Answer (score 21):

[Puts Mail](http://www.putsmail.com) is the best bet these days.  Check out [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742562/941516) by the creator of Puts Mail.

Answer (score 4):

I would use python, here at the bottom is an example how to create a HTML email with a text default: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html
you can parameterize this, encapsulate in functions, read content from files, etc. (make sure, that you set localhost in "s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost') " to your smtp server)

Comment: As at 01-31-2020, the link provided above is broken

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to test whether an HTML email displays properly in various clients, I would use [sendmail.exe](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) (windows only).

You can save a .html file and pipe it into that program on the command-line as the email content. There are command line options for from/to/subject/server, etc.

This would allow you to rapidly send and re-send emails by just editing the .html file and running the command-line again. No programming required.

Edit: there is a similar command-line tool for Linux with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I would **not** even go **with any language** ...

I would stop at [**MailChimp**](http://www.mailchimp.com/) and set up a [free account](http://www.mailchimp.com/signup/) (max of 500 subscribers and 3000 sends per month) ... 3000 sends is enough to test right? :)

It has all the tools you need to send emails professionally (and maybe set up an account to your client/friend so they/he can use MailChimp in their Newsletters)

while you're at it, see their [resources](http://www.mailchimp.com/resources/) page as well the perfect tool to know what can we use in Newsletters using [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) own [Guide to CSS support in email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

hope it helps

Comment: *caugh* You wouldn't happen to work at MailChimp by any chance..?

Comment: nahh, just a happy user :) and I use Campaign Monitor as well :D

Comment: It takes a few minutes of set up, but this was a very easy and reliable way to send HTML emails. Just make a custom template, and you can write and test your own HTML emails.

Comment: This is no longer possible with a free account, it requires the "standard" account at $14.99USD/mo. to use a "custom" template. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Ruby variant:

```
require "mail"

options = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "me@gmail.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :authentication       => :plain,
}

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

mail = Mail.new do
  to      "me@gmail.com"
  from    "Me Me me@gmail.com"
  subject "test email"

  html_part do
    content_type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    body File.read("index.html")
  end
end

mail.deliver
```

Do not forget to enable access from https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1):

If you are running .NET and you have a Gmail account this is one easy way

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
           {
               Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               Port = 587,
               EnableSsl = true,
               DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false,
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
           };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                     {
                         Subject = subject,
                         Body = body
                     })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

see [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1) for more details

Comment: There isn't actually an SMTP server built into .Net.  Just classes for interacting with an existing SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can send html emails from Mozilla's Thunderbird email client.

http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/

This is what I used to send test emails.  Or I guess you could use your email provider too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac you can send HTML email super quickly using Safari and Mail.  I blogged about the details at the link below, but basically you just view your HTML file in Safari and select File > Mail Contents of This Page.

http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/send-html-email-with-safari-mail-for-fast-testing/

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the conversation, but here is the quickest method (although far from best practice) to send a html email:

View your *rendered* html in a web browser (like a web page), then `ctrl+a` select the entire page then `ctrl+c` copy and `ctrl+v` paste that rendered html result into the body of your email. Doesn't get any easier than that...

Just note that your images need to be hosted if you want the recipient to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I send HTML email (often in bulk) using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/). It has worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [PowerShell](http://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+send+email)

Answer (score 0):

A Windows-only free solution where you typically don't have to install anything special is to use ASP or WSH. I opt for JScript instead of VBScript:

```
function sendHtml(recipients, subject, html) {
    var mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message");

    mail.From = "Tester <tester@example.com>";
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.To = recipients.join(";");
    mail.HTMLBody = html;

    // Do the following if you want to directly use a specific SMTP server
    mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2;
    mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")
        = "smtp.example.com";
    mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")
        = 25;
    mail.Configuration.Fields.Update();

    mail.Send();
}
```

**Note:** However, your HTML may end up getting slightly reformatted with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendHtml(recipients, subject, html) {
var mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message");

mail.From = "Tester <tester@example.com>";
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.To = recipients.join(";");
mail.HTMLBody = html;

// Do the following if you want to directly use a specific SMTP server
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2;
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")
    = "smtp.example.com";
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")
    = 25;
mail.Configuration.Fields.Update();

mail.Send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I know I am almost a decade and a half late to this...

But you can send HTML emails extremely easily with Thunderbird Mail.

1. Click write to compose new mail
2. Click into the body of the email
3. Insert --> HTML

Although you do have to paste the content into the box that pops up, instead of sending a file itself.

Remember to double check that your account settings and email specific settings are set to allow HTML emails (I believe this is default).

[Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) is free, cross platform (Mac, Windows & Linux), open source, & maintained by Mozilla.

Edit: I have no affiliation with Thunderbird or Mozilla.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use System.Net.Mail in .NET?

You can read from an email template and assing to a MailMessage body.

To send email

```
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = CreateMailMessage();

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
            sc.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"];
            sc.Port = 0x19;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            sc.Send(msg);
```