# HTML email in outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm making a template for email in html, it works fine in apple email clients, gmail, hotmail and windows mail 2006. It does not work in outlook, it stretches out, the font family is not working and because it stretches out it does not center on the page.

This is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.5">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:                     0; 
    padding:                    0; 
    width:                      100% !important; 
    overflow-y:                 hidden; 
    background-color:           #ffffff; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:   100%; 
    -ms-text-size-adjust:       100%; 
    font-family:                Helvetica;
    vertical-align:             top;
    border-spacing:             0px;
}
ul, ol, dl { 
    padding:                    0;
    margin:                     0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top:                 0;  
    padding-right:              0px;
    padding-left:               0px; 
}
a img { 
    border:                     none;
}
a:link {
    color:                      #42413C;
    text-decoration:            underline;
}
a:visited {
    color:                      #6E6C64;
    text-decoration:            underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
    text-decoration:            none;
}
.container {
    width:                      600px;
    background:                 #FFF;
    margin:                     0 auto; 
}

.content {
    padding:                    0px;
    padding-left:               10px;
    border:                     none;
    background-color:           #E9E9E9;
    line-height:                16px; 
    font-size:                  14px;
    width:                      590px;
}
.footer {
    padding:                    0px 0;
    background:                 #000000;
    text-align:                 center;
    color:                      white;
    font-size:                  12px;
    margin-bottom:              10px;
    height:                     45px;
    width:                      600px;
}
.actie {
    background-color:           #69696D;
}
.icons {
    font-size:                  12px;
}
.contact {
    text-align:                 center;
}
.table {
    border-spacing:             0px;
}
.contact a {
    color:                      white;
}
.devices {
    background-color:           #2f2f31; 
    height:                     253px;
    border:                     0;
}
.header {
    background-color:           #2f2f31; 
    height:                     87px;
    border:                     0;
}
p {
    font-color:                 black;
}

</style></head>

<body>

<div class="container" width="600px" height="900px">
  <div class="header"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/logo.png" width="600" height="87px" />
  </div> 
  <div class="devices" background-color="#2f2f31" height="220px" border="0"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/devices2.png" /></div>
  <div class="content">
    <table width="590" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="55%"><h3><strong>Werkt u al met apps?</strong></h3>
          <p>Het gebruik van applicaties, oftewel apps, is namelijk booming! Steeds meer merken en bedrijven zien het gemak van een app in. Het is de ideale optie voor het versterken van uw merk, zowel extern als intern, of het opzetten van een geheel nieuw product. Ook de enorme groei in gebruik van mobiele apparaten zorgt er voor dat een sterk merk niet meer kan achter blijven.</p>
          <p>Mocht u geïnteresseerd zijn in onze service, van op maat gemaakte applicaties en backend oplossingen, neem dan gerust contact met ons op. U bent van harte welkom voor een kop koffie bij ons in de Suikersilo's, tijdens een verkennend gesprek of een demonstratie van de mogelijkheden van apps voor mobiel, tablets, tv en het web.</p>
        <p>Alvast bedankt en hopelijk tot ziens.</p></td>
        <td width="45%" valign="top">
        <table height="auto" border="0" cellpadding="5px" class="icons" margin-top="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h3>No matter what device.<br />
              We build natively.</h3></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/apple.png"/></td>
            <td width="199"><div align="center">Apple iOS is the operating<br />
              system that powers the <br />
              iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.</div></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/android.png"  /></td>
            <td><div align="center">With partners like Google,<br />
              HTC and Motorola, Android is<br />
              the fastest growing mobile OS.</div></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/windows.png" /></td>
            <td><div align="center">Together Microsoft and Nokia<br />
              support conventional users <br />
              with Windows Phone.</div></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/html5.png" /></td>
            <td><div align="center">Looking for other platforms<br />
              like BlackBerry, Samsung <br />
              Bada or HTML5 &amp; CSS3?<br />
              We can build it!</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></div>
    <div class="actie">
      <div align="center"><a href="http://www.mediabunker.com/products"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/actie2.png" /></a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="footer" background-color="#000000" halign="center" height="40px">
    <table class="contact" border="0" HALIGN="center">
      <tr align="center">
        <td align="center" width="189px"><font color="white">Suikersilo-West 23 <br />
        1165 MP Halfweg</font></td>
        <td align="center" width="189px"><a href="tel:0031238200140">Tel +31 23 820 0140</a><br> <a href="mailto:info@mediabunker.com">info@mediabunker.com</a></td>
        <td align="center" width="189px"><a href="http://mediabunker.com">www.mediabunker.com</a><br> <a href="http://twitter.com/mediabunker">twitter.com/mediabunker</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<img src="http://mediabunker.com/newsletters/newsletter_201206/footer.png" width="600"/></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with fixing this for outlook? Have I used any elements that are not supported by outlook? Do I need more inline css?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd suggest having a look at [www.emailology.org](http://www.emailology.org). I've found it very useful when building emails for Outlook. As a rule for HTML emails, I build them purely in tables and with styles on the elements. It's horrible and like building bad websites years ago but unfortunatly it seems to be the best solution available.

For example, I'd change `<p>` to `<p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">` and so on. Build it and style it like you would do normally but when you are happy enough to test it copy all the styles inline.

Have a look at Emailology though. It's a great resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion website :-).

Comment: Ah...finally! Thanks Jane :)

Comment: @SpaceBeers Hi SpaceBeers, I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003595/email-design-looking-different-in-outlook-in-comparison-to-other-email-clients/51003795?noredirect=1#comment89001186_51003795). I am wondering if you can help me out.

Comment: @user5447339 Sure what's up?

Comment: @SpaceBeers I have a similar question related to the html email issue in Outlook. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @user5447339 What is your question?

Comment: @SpaceBeers This is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003595/email-design-looking-different-in-outlook-in-comparison-to-other-email-clients/51003795?noredirect=1#comment89001186_51003795).

Comment: @SpaceBeers My html emails are looking extremely different in outlook. I am wondering what can be the reason behind it. I have mentioned by code in the fiddle there in the question. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 7):

This site provides a nice table overview (PDF download possible) of which CSS attributes will work with which email clients, what CSS selectors are supported, and where to define your CSS style (style tag vs. head style vs. inline):

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

This post provides additional sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019166/1143126

Answer (score 1):

there are a huge number of guides out there that will help you with this as outlook is realy flaky with HTML, for example it dosent support nested 's which you are using.