# Tables wont stay the same width when viewed in Outlook

Tags: html, html-table

I am creating an email form using about 4 tables. Each one is meant to be 700px wide overall so it looks flush all the way down but some table near the bottom are either in or out a few pixels.

I am running the email form through Mailchimp and it only looks out of shape once I view it in Outlook.

This is one of the tables that I want to be 700px but is showing at about 696px:

```
<table width="700px" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th width="16" bgcolor="#efefef" scope="row"></th>
<td width="664" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#efefef">
<font size="2">TEXT TEXT TEX</font></td>
<td width="14" bgcolor="#efefef">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="39" bgcolor="#efefef" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
<td bgcolor="#efefef">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here's my CSS (but I can't see that being the problem):

```
body,td,th {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
h2 {
color: #f16b20;
font-size: large;
}
body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h3 {
font-size: 12px;
}
a:link {
color: #f16b20;
}
a:visited {
color: #f16b20;
}
a:hover {
color: #993300;
}
a:active {
color: #f16b20;
}
```

Comment: You should remove the deprecated tags you are using, like `<font>`, also you can define, width and height to your td's using CSS, you don't need to use attributes there, same goes for `bgcolor`

Comment: `table width="700px"` should just be `table width="700"`

Comment: Do not use width and height as attribute (they are deprecated) but use CSS instead (`style="width: <your width>; height: <your height>;"` in your tag as attribute). I was having same issue with Firefox not interpreting well percentage in these attributes. A great thing to use is `table-layout: fixed;` as it do not deform the table if the content is huge, it use the style of the first line.

Comment: @pete Thanks mate, that's sorted it! so simple but I just missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you do away with CSS and use your styles inline.

Since Web standards concerning CSS are not applied in a consistent manner by email clients you are better off applying your styles directly to the elements.

Here are a couple of helpful explanations on why not to use CSS as you would on the web.

[HTML email: tables or divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935472/html-email-tables-or-divs)

[HTML email in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137540/html-email-in-outlook)