# Best online tool to test the view of newsletter?

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-validation

does anyone knows a online tool to see how the html of a newsletter looks like?
I mean a tool which I put my HTML code in and he gives me screenshots of e-mail clients or something similiar.

Thanks

Comment: Your question was actually asked and effectively answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018078/testing-html-email-rendering

Comment: That answer is insufficient, its more an add to services of single company in behind. So this question is still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of one tool that allows you to test how an e-mail client interprets the HTML you have written called [Litmus](http://litmus.com/). It is a tool you will have to pay for, but there is a 7 day trial. 
 [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) also provides a similar type of service.

Aside from using a tool to test your e-mail newsletters, there is a lot written on what can and cannot be done when markin up e-mail newsletters. [This article](http://www.kratedesign.com/blog/2010/04/28/avoiding-pitfalls-and-building-better-html-email/) has a couple of good suggestions to effectively markup compatible e-mail newsletters. Beyond that [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/html/email-marketing-field-guide/) has a field guide to creating good e-mail newsletters. This guide runs the gamut from design to markup.