# Confusion about css coding standards for Html Email newsletter

Tags: html, css, newsletter, email-templates

i am  coding   Email newsletters. i have seen some guidelines regarding Good email coding.. 
i want to  ask about css code for Email newsletters  for example  its  preffered to code inline  css but for  some free templates i found   code  like this

```
       <style type="text/css">

       body { color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sansserif; text-align:center; }
       h2 { color:#2255DB; font-size:16px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:0px; }        
       h2 a:link { text-decoration:none; }
      .footer { fontsize:11px; text-align:center; color:#2255DB; }// and son on 

       </style>
```

in body code for fotter is like

```
    <p class="footer" style="color:#2255DB;"> footer...</footer>//again style  tag
```

and sometimes  i found like this  total inline styling ..

```
    <span style="font-weight: bold; width: 525px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolo
    </span><br><br>// and son on  ,,
```

Both the above mentioned codes are  working fine in Email clients 
i have also seen standards from Campaign monitor  etc, so i am confused which style is better .. should we use style in  as in above mentioned code and or total inline coding   ,   Please if someone can clear me about this ..it would be great favor

**EDIT**  : 
   once coded is there any free service that can help to check if its valid code for mail clients ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey  i am working as freelancer and given 2  newsletters to check css coding standards , so i wanted to myself  clear about it ,1 given newsletter uses first scheme  and second is using 2 and both are working fine  so was confusing for me how to see   (its a test task for me for a long term project)

Comment: No idea why this is down voted. +1 just to negate.

Comment: Yes , its pretty helpful and will be for those who visit it later .

Comment: Campaign Monitor has a tool to inline your css before it sends. They suggest putting it in the header with the intent that they will auto inline it for you when you send it through Campaign Monitor. If you want a similar css inlining tool try [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) or [Inline Styler](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the HTML newsletter looks as close as the designs I would definitely use inline styling.

Unfortunately you have to be very specific with your styling, otherwise some software (Gmail for instance) will override your style declarations. It is a real pain sometimes, but it's worth doing it that way IMO.

Same thing goes for HTML email signatures.

**So definitely go for the inline styling :)**

Oh, and one more thing. I know that it's 2012 and loads of designers/front-enders advice to use html tags (even html5 elements) in HTML emails and signatures, but I'd try to stick to the old-school way and use tables to make sure there is no unnecessary artefacts with the code.

Comment: ok , once coded is there any free service that  can help to check if its valid code for   mail clients ?

Comment: I believe Campaign monitor has their own one (only for their customers though), let me check for other stuff, I think I've met one or two lately...

Comment: i  have been using putsmail.com  thats awesome , but that is not working for me for last 2 days ,not getting emails once sent

Comment: I've found these: http://www.emailonacid.com/ and http://litmus.com/email-testing. I believe with some googling you'll be able to find good ones on the interwebs.

Comment: There is another thread, which should definitely answer your added question about the testing tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018078/testing-html-email-rendering

Comment: No problem at all. Please consider accepting my answer if you're happy with it :) Cheers!

Comment: can u pelas give me once more favor  , is there any difference between the code of  email for Mobile  or pc , i mean  is this same coding or there is any difference , For me i think coding is same but just few standards are to be met   am i right ?  Thanks

Comment: The table based, inline styled version should be rendered correctly everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

For email newsletter formats, as different email clients renders the layouts differently, I would strongly suggest you use **inline css** and primarily **font tag and its attributes** to styling the texts. Also use Table structure instead of div layouts to keep the layout consistent across most of the email clients.

Answer (score 1):

Many mail clients will remove embedded stylesheets. It's best to use inline styles for everything.

In your example, you're styling the BODY tag - but if I read your email in Gmail - the page already has its OWN body tag - so yours will be stripped out.

I've found the campaign monitor guide to be an excellent resource to follow.

Here's a good test: save your email at a static HTML page, then open it on MS Word. It's a pretty good "worst-case scenario".

If you are going to be doing any serious email marketing work, [Exact Target](http://www.exacttarget.com/) has an excellent tool that will actually render-out your email in different clients and give you a PDF of screen shots from those platforms to review.

Comment: Should use a 100% width "fake body table" in there also. This will act as your body tag when gmail strips it out. Another tip: Set that as your desired bgcolor, and leave the body tag white, if someone forwards your email, they can type on a white bg, while your designed area remains in your set bgcolor. (Important if you have a dark background)

Answer (score 1):

From the HTML emails I have done, as well as following the advice from http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails/, I would recommend always putting styles inline.

You mentioned http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, which does show that Gmail would be the client where styles would have issues not being inline.

Edit: If there is any interest on why Gmail is the black sheep in this scenario, check out Section 1194.22, http://mail.google.com/mail/help/accessibility.html

Answer (score 1):

Creating HTML templates for email is a real hassle. Testing is also often extremely difficult and unreliable, even from services which say they test everything. Older mail clients are known to ignore CSS and newer HTML elements. Additionally, a mail client may override some of your CSS with its own, mangling the layout.

My advice:

1) Use inline styles, as other people mentioned. Apply them to EVERYTHING. For example, don't expect adding a font-size to a div to apply to a `<p>` inside the div (as it should!). Add the style to both, or at least the immediate parent.

2) Use tables for any layout (ugh!), rather than margins and paddings. Some older mail clients could care less about CSS, and may strip all of yours out, or only apply snippets of it.

3) Design the email in a way that it is still readable even if the email client discards all your CSS (which is a distinct possibility). This is why you often receive email newsletters that are mostly images.

Answer (score 0):

**Use inline styles for everything** to ensure that your HTML email displays the same on all clients.

There is a good tool you can use for inlining your HTML content. It is provided by mail-chimp (who i guess know a thing or two about emails) http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use inline styles rather then embedded css because some major email clients (such as Outlook 2007) do not support CSS in emails.

Gmail doesn't support embedded CSS.

One way to get around this issue is to convert your embedded CSS into inline using our CSS conversion tool in the "Developer Tools" dropdown in each test result.

There is another way of getting around the issue for things like font, font color and font size: Gmail converts your Body tag to a DIV. That can actually work to your advantage because you can use any inline CSS properties within your BODY that would otherwise be supported by a DIV. It is important to know, however, that some clients do not support the BODY tag so you should also include the same declarations within your embedded CSS. Also, keep in mind, you cant rely on BODY attributes like "bgcolor" because it is not supported within a DIV