# Table cell height issue in emails

Tags: html, css, email

I have the following code in a html email:

```
<table style="margin: 32px 0; border: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;">Invoice Number</td>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;">Tax Point</td>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;">30/11/2017 11:48:32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;">Payer ID</td>
        <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 1; background: red;">Senior Internet</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="invoice-items">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px;">Description</th>
        <th style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px;">Item Amount</th>
        <th style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px;">Quantity</th>
        <th style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px;">VAT Amount</th>
        <th style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px;">Line Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">Charity/ public sector</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">360.0000</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">1</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">72.0000</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">360.0000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="no-border">Total</td>
        <td class="green no-border">£432.0000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, I am having an issue with the cell height of the first table coming out far too large. I've tried setting padding, borders, line heights, I just can't get the red cells to be the height of the text within them.[image]

Comment: you have to add your css because your code  working properly this way, the problem mostly from the css

Comment: dont post here template file with placeholders like `{{DueDate}}` but paste here rendered html,,

Comment: If you inspect the element can you see anything overriding the inline styles?  Eg are the styles of the email client adding padding to the table cells?  Is the table margin somehow being added to the cells (as it isn't being added to the table)

Comment: @pete I can't inspect the email as it is in outlook, I will try getting one into gmail and see what I can find, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `line-height` in plain `px` instead?

Comment: Just tried setting line-height in px, no difference. It all appears fine in gmail, just seems to having issues in Outlook 2016

Answer (score 0):

It's something about the CSS you're using or the email client, your code is working properly here, checkout how it is rendered in plain HTML file:

[image: How it is rendered in plain HTML]

Check out this answer for testing HTML templates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019166/4129382