# Browser only shows inlined text-indent property

Tags: html, css, html-email, inline

I'm editing a piece of html email template.

I've been trying to apply `text-indent` property to a text using an styling as following:

```
 <style>
#Indent {text-indent:1em}
</style>

<p id="Indent">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
```

But it doesn't run properly in browser.
At the same time inline styling for this property runs perfectly well in broswer:

```
<p style="text-indent:1em">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
```

All other stylings in the document I did using id attribute and they work perfectly fine.

Is there a way to style `text-indent` in the similar manner so I won't have to make a single inline styling in a single document?

Comment: Does changing `<style>` to  `<style type="text/css">` fix the problem ?

Comment: Running your code I get no problem, the text indents OK. Please make your code into a snippet and see whether you get the problem. I don't think the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Can you provide the entire email template please ? What browser are you using ? Do you open the HTML file directly in the browser or do you use a webtool to render the template ?

Comment: @Tom I'm testing it on Firefox. What are popular webtools to render html?

Comment: @DKtl I was thinking about one of [these tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019166/16688813) for example (most of them are not free). Anyway, it would be easier to help you if you could provide the entire code.

Comment: In general, for HTML email, you must inline everything. Try *not* to use `<style>`. This is because many email clients strip out `<style>`.